# SQL — insert values into table which it doesn't already have that are in a list

Tags: sql, t-sql

Out of a list of 44 values, I need to insert whichever of those values are not already contained in a table. It already has 35 of them. How do I write a SQL statement to insert only the other 9? I'll shorten the list just to make the code more readable. I'm starting out by just trying to create a select. The problem is that this returns ALL the rows in the table that aren't in my list (over 800), not just the values FROM MY LIST that aren't in the target table. So, in the following list, if the table has Acquia, AngularJS, BitBucket, and Blockchain, I only want my query returning (or inserting) Xamarin.

```
select *
from Technology t
where not exists
(
select 1
from
(values ('Acquia'),
('AngularJS'),
('BitBucket'),
('Blockchain'),
('Xamarin')) as TempTable(Name)
where t.Name = TempTable.Name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `where` clause to filter out the ones that already exist:

```
with list as (
      select name
      from (values () . . . ) v
     )
insert into t (name)
     select name
     from list
     where not exists (select 1 from t where t.name = list.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO Technology 
SELECT .... 
FROM ... //new values
EXCEPT
select *
from Technology t;
```

More information about [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) - basically, you are selecting all values from the first `SELECT` except these rows, that are already returned by (contained in) second `SELECT`.